# if statement calling functions and improper result

Tags: shell-script, rhel

The shell script is expected to call only one function, but calling both. How to fix this, the output is

both are same

both are not same

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=ORCL
var2=ORCL

function f1    
{  
    echo "both are same"
}

function f2
{
    echo "both are not same"
}

if [ $var1=$var2 ]; 
then
    f1  
fi

if [ $var1!=$var2 ]; 
then
    f2
fi
```

Comment: you're missing spaces.

Comment: @muru Welcome back!  **:-)**  *I missed you!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*spaces* are required when relational operators are used in ***if*** condition

Ex:

```
if [ $var1 = $var2 ] ;

if [ $var1 != $var2 ] ;
```

> Modified script

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=ORCL
var2=ORCL

f1()
{
echo "both are same"
}

f2()
{
echo "both are not same"
}

if [ $var1 = $var2 ];
then
        f1
fi

if [ $var1 != $var2 ];
then
        f2
fi
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on if/why this is an answer to the question/solution to the problem?

Comment: he didn't use spaces for the relational operators in the `if` condition .

Comment: Please improve your answer. Edit your answer to include the information, so that it explains to people why the code you posted helps with the question.

Comment: Hope I've added the missing information in detail. :-)

Comment: The reason is that `[` is actually a program / builtin that takes a list of space separated arguments, followed by a final argument of `]`. If you omit the spaces then `$var1` `!=` `$var2` `]` (4 arguments) becomes `$var1!=$var2` `]` (2 arguments), which is invalid.

Comment: @JShorthouse perfect! ..

Answer (score 2):

You need to add spaces.

Replace

```
if [ $var1=$var2 ];
```

with

```
if [ "$var1" = "$var2" ];
```

same for the second `if` statement.